# How to close default gallery programmatically?

Tags: android, image-gallery

I am using this code

```
    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    photoPickerIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    photoPickerIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(photoPickerIntent, "Image File Picker"), 1000);
```

to pick image from sdcard within my application.

this is working fine, according to my requirement i need to close that ACTION_PICK chooserActivity myself, like when we touch outside the dialog that will closed fine...

but how can we close this type of dialog programmatically?

Comment: Are you displaying that Gallery image pick activity as a Dialog?

Comment: no.. i am talking about that chooser dialog which will display all filemanager app from your device....

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

That chooser is actually a separate activity, launched by intent (which will then launch another activity via intent when the user selects something).

You don't control that chooser, its not actually in your app.