# How can i dismiss the dialog created from Intent.Action Pick to get Gallery images?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using an Intent to get Gallery Images,which result in a dialog to choose an option.
I am using this intent

```
 Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

            startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 123);
```

But i want this dialog to get dimiss when i touch outside the dialog.Also i am using Fragment

Comment: use  dialog.dismiss();

Comment: what is exact requirement?

Comment: i got the solution it cannot be done here http://stackoverflow.com/a/16663303/563735

Answer (score 0):

Use this: `yournameofdialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);`

But I think that its not a dialog, its a new activity. To cancel this, use Back button of the device.

Hope it helps

Comment: i want touch event not back pressed

Answer (score 0):

use this it may help

```
Dialogname.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
```

or this

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
```

{

```
   if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE){  
    System.out.println("TOuch outside the dialog ******************** ");  
           this.dismiss();  
   }  
   return false;
```

}

Comment: its an intent to launch dialog,i dont the name of the dialog